# Bluetooth communication of android device with raspberrypi -getting error as connection refused

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, bluez, connection-refused

I have tried socket programming for Bluetooth communication with raspberrypi. But every time I am getting connection refused as error .I have installed all necessary  Bluetooth packages on pi.

```
client code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc addr = { 0 };
    int s, status;
    char dest[18] = "01:23:45:67:89:AB";

// allocate a socket
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

// set the connection parameters (who to connect to)
addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
str2ba( dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr );

// connect to server
status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

// send a message
if( status == 0 ) {
    status = write(s, "hello!", 6);
}

if( status < 0 ) perror("uh oh");

close(s);
return 0;
```

}
Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
   char buf[1024] = { 0 };
   int s, client, bytes_read;
   socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

// allocate socket
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

// bind socket to port 1 of the first available 
// local bluetooth adapter
loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

// put socket into listening mode
listen(s, 1);

// accept one connection
client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

// read data from the client
bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
    printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
}

// close connection
close(client);
close(s);
return 0;
```

}

when visibility of my device is off then it says "host is down"
And when visibility is on and when I pair device it says connection is refused.

Comment: Which version of BlueZ are you using? Can you try running the same sequence but from the command line? On the server side run "rfcomm listen 1" and on the client side run "rfcomm connect 0 00:11:22:33:44:55 4". You can also run "btmon &", which forces btmon to run in the background and show you more verbose messages.

Comment: I have tried that way too.I am using Bluez 5.48 currently.